# Setting fullscreen in Tao Opengl

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

Using the SimpleOpenGlControl from [Tao.Platform.Windows](http://docs.taoframework.com/Tao.Platform.Windows/), how can I set it to fullscreen mode, or will I have to use glut?

**My Solution**

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is some discussion](http://www.taoframework.com/node/598) about setting SimpleOpenGlControl to fullscreen.

Comment: The site is down... What was their solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine and has been tested to work as expected under all circumstances (speaking as a Tao & OpenTK developer).